# How to get DataFrame of 249 Countries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to store country names in dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry

countries = pd.DataFrame()

for i in list(pycountry.countries):
    i=dict(i)
    print(i)
    countries['alpha_3'] = i['alpha_3']
    countries['name'] = i['name']
    countries['original_name'] = i['original_name']

print(countries.head())
```

**Error** : TypeError: 'Country' object is not iterable

Thanks for Solution in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute `original_name` in `Country` object.

```py
data = [[country.alpha_3, country.name] for country in pycountry.countries]

countries = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['alpha_3', 'name'])
```

```
# print(countries.head())

  alpha_3           name
0     ABW          Aruba
1     AFG    Afghanistan
2     AGO         Angola
3     AIA       Anguilla
4     ALA  Åland Islands
```

You can also create it like

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([country.__dict__['_fields'] for country in pycountry.countries])
```

```
print(df.head())

  alpha_2 alpha_3           name numeric                    official_name common_name
0      AW     ABW          Aruba     533                              NaN         NaN
1      AF     AFG    Afghanistan     004  Islamic Republic of Afghanistan         NaN
2      AO     AGO         Angola     024               Republic of Angola         NaN
3      AI     AIA       Anguilla     660                              NaN         NaN
4      AX     ALA  Åland Islands     248                              NaN         NaN
```

Then use `df.loc[['alpha_2', 'alpha_3']]` to select columns.

Answer (score 2):

All the counties listed in `pycountry.countries` do not have an `official_name` attribute.

For those countries, we can set `None` in `official_name` column.

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry

countries = pd.DataFrame()
data = []
for country in pycountry.countries:
    try:
        current = {'alpha_3': country.alpha_3,
                    'name': country.name,
                    'official_name': country.official_name}
    except Exception as ex:
        current = {'alpha_3': country.alpha_3,
                    'name': country.name,
                    'official_name': None}        
    data.append(current)

countries = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['alpha_3', 'name', 'official_name'])
print(countries.head())
```

**Output:**

```
  alpha_3           name                    official_name
0     ABW          Aruba                             None
1     AFG    Afghanistan  Islamic Republic of Afghanistan
2     AGO         Angola               Republic of Angola
3     AIA       Anguilla                             None
4     ALA  Åland Islands                             None
```